# Ways to generate symmetric and asymmetric keys

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, random, asymmetric

We are using Beaglebone Black based custom board, and want to use hybrid encryption for encrypting firmware file, i.e. symmetric for encryption big firmware file and asymmetric for encrypting symmetric key file. I refer to [this](http://bikulov.org/blog/2013/10/12/hybrid-symmetric-asymmetric-encryption-for-large-files/) blog for hybrid encryption idea.

Now regarding generation of the symmetric key and asymmetric keys (mainly in Bash script) I have the following doubts.

### Symmetric key

**Method 1:**

```
openssl rand 128 > sym_keyfile.key
```

**Doubt 1:**

How does the length of the key, e.g. 128, 192 or 256, affect encryption and decryption? Is is only time taken for encryption and decryption?

**Method 2:**

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -n 128 > sym_keyfile.key
```

**Method 3:**

```
cat /dev/random | head -n 128 > sym_keyfile.key
```

**Doubt 2:**

Which method is more random, Method 1 or Method 2? I am inclined to think that Method 2 is random enough and the manual page of `random, urandom` suggest to use `urandom` in case one is not sure about it.
However we have seed enough entropy to generate more secure random number.

**Doubt 3:**

Can we ask OpenSSL to take random number from `/dev/urandom`?

### Asymmetric key

**Private key generation:**

```
openssl genrsa -out keyfile.key 4096
```

**Public key generation from private key:**

```
openssl rsa -in keyfile.key -pubout -out keyfile.pub
```

Now when I read OpenSSL help regarding `rsa` it says:

> The rsa command processes RSA keys. They can be converted between various forms and their components printed out. Note this command uses the traditional SSLeay compatible format for private key encryption: newer applications should use the more secure PKCS#8 format using the pkcs8 utility.

**Doubt 4:**

Is OpenSSL help suggesting to use `pkcs#8` for generating both the private and public key or only for generating the public key from the private key?

**Doubt 5:**

Do you suggest any other method to generate more secure asymmetric keys?

Comment: PKCS has says something about how the key information is STORED not how its generated.

Comment: @LvB Thank you for attention, so does it mean it would still remain the same RSA key but the way it is stored is more secure ? There is PKCS12 also so which one to choose?

Comment: To point 5: Maybe a highly subjective and biased personal opinion of mine: I personally prefer to use my own software to generate RSA keys, cf. s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Thank you for comment, I was looking for alternative key generation methods using openssl(mainly) or other tools.

Comment: The ``num`` argument for ``openssl rand`` is interpreted as number of **bytes**, not number of **bits**. An AES-128 expects a key of 128 **bit**, 16 **byte**. To generate such a key, use OpenSSL as: openssl rand 16 > myaes.key AES-256 expects a key of 256 bit, 32 byte. To generate such a key, use: openssl rand 32 > myaes.key

Comment: And `head -n N` counts _lines_ not bytes _or_ bits, so it will give a much larger and varying amount of key material; `head -c $bytes` would come closer to sanity. But also not just UUOC but actually HUOC = Harmful Use of cat because it will typically run a full pipeline buffer ahead of `head`. And in addition to `pkcs8` OpenSSL since release 1.0.0 in 2010 `pkey` converts to PKCS8 and `genpkey` generates RSA _and_ other asymmetric keys in PKCS8 to start with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to ask for a comparative study on the PRNG (pseudo-random number generators) used by default by OpenSSL and the Linux kernel. This could most probably fill a volume full of mathematical formulas, and to make it worse OpenSSL and the Linux PRNG are not independent since [OpenSSL will use */dev/urandom* as a default seed](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers), and there are ongoing work to provide an alternative PRNG for Linux (you can see Stephan Müller work on the subject [here](http://www.chronox.de/lrng/doc/lrng.pdf) and [there](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2014/ols2014-mueller.pdf) and also his discussions on the linux kernel mailing list).

However, the fact is that in most cases both will share the same strengths and weaknesses:

- Strength: both are mature and well audited code generally accepted as cryptographically secure PRNG,
- Weakness: as their name state they both are *pseudo* random number generator, meaning they both are deterministic algorithms which, given the same seeds, will produce the same output. The unpredictability of the produced numbers is therefore directly dependent on the unpredictability of the seeds.

So, security-wise, your main concern here may not be which one from OpenSSL or `/dev/urandom` to use (especially when you know now that the former relies on the latter behind the scene), but to ensure the quality of the seeding. In particular, what you *may* want is one or several sources of TRNG (True Random Number Generator), ie. some *hardware* component specially designed to serve unpredictable random data suitable for cryptography.

This will guaranty you that the quality of the seeds used by the above mentioned algorithms will not be dependent on external factors as the system I/O, load, etc. (when available these entropy sources will most likely still be used, but merged with the TRNG input). In most situations, this will have more impact on your overall keys strengths than choosing between two well-established PRNG implementations.

Now to answer your doubts:

> **Doubt 1:**
>
> How does the length of the key, e.g. 128, 192 or 256, affect
>   encryption and decryption? Is is only time taken for encryption and
>   decryption?

Yes, it is: larger key require more computational power to encrypt and decrypt. The idea behind this is that, while it will require more efforts from the legitimate devices knowing the right key, it will also require "exponentially" more effort from any potential attacker.

Regarding the right length, you will already find a lot of discussions on this website on this subject ([like this nice table](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/80785/32746)), with some general cases and some taking some constraints into account (like embedded devices which have very limited computational power).

> **Doubt 2:**
>
> Which method is more random, Method 1 or Method 2? I am inclined to
>   think that Method 2 is random enough and the manual page of random,
>   urandom suggest to use urandom in case one is not sure about it.
>   However we have seed enough entropy to generate more secure random
>   number.

Method 3 may block suddenly and for an undetermined amount of time. If this not what you want (and usually you don't want this), then the choice is indeed between methods 1 and 2.

From there, the choice is merely a matter of personal preference. I would say that the syntax using OpenSSL is more portable, and easier which can help to avoid bugs (for instance using `-n` (number of lines) instead of `-c` (number of bytes) as parameter of the `head` command ;) ).

> **Doubt 3:**
>
> Can we ask OpenSSL to take random number from /dev/urandom?

This is the default behavior, but if you want to ensure this OpenSSL documentation is your friend and would advise you to add the `-rand` parameter:

```
openssl rand -rand /dev/urandom 128 > sym_keyfile.key
```

> **Doubt 4:**
>
> Is OpenSSL help suggesting to use pkcs#8 for generating both the
>   private and public key or only for generating the public key from the
>   private key?

As stated in LvB comment, this is about how the keys are *stored*, and not generated (this is like storing a file in either a `.zip`, `.rar` or `.tar.gz` archive).

In case you have a free choice, OpenSSL indeed advises you to use modern and standardized formats instead of the historical SSLeay format:

- With PKCS8 you will store the private key in one (possibly encrypted) file, and the public key / certificate in another (plaintext) file.
- With PKCS12 you will bundle both the private and public components in a single file (which may seem more practical but implies that if the `.p12` file is encrypted, then even the public certificate will not be readable without deciphering the file first).

Practically, the choice will often be down to what is supported by the applications which will use the keys. Its documentation will often mandate you where and how to store the key material.

> **Doubt 5:**
>
> Do you suggest any other method to generate more secure asymmetric
>   keys?

I already mentioned TRNG devices above, and I would also advise you to stay on known land by using mature and well known software implementations. Software implementing poor algorithms or good algorithms but with a buggy implementation can equally annihilate your security.

And at last, stay informed since [mistakes can happen everywhere](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html), but they are most likely to be detected and solved soon in well-established solutions than in exotic ones.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to implement hybrid encryption yourself, I'd recommend using `openssl smime` subcommand. Another option is to use `gpg`, which is probably much more suitable than openssl for signing and encrypting files.

Both `openssl smime` and `gpg` does hybrid encryption automatically.